# Adding store-bought juice to beer

Tags: beer

I've been toying with the idea of adding roughly a gallon of white grape juice to a beer (possibly a Belgian Blonde?) but was previously told that the juice will just be completely fermented out by the yeast, leaving me with a lighter bodied beer but with no flavor from the juice.

However, after researching cider more it seems that many people do ferment store-bought juice without issue. I've even found some references to people successfully adding juice to beer. So overall I'm a bit confused at this point.

I'm not necessarily looking for a huge fruity flavor in such a beer but I definitely want it to be noticeable. Have other people had success using store-bought juice in beer (or even cider)? Even if all the sugars get fermented out, wouldn't there still be esters and the like that would contribute flavor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the label ingredients. If it mentions Metabisulfide as a preservative it will kill fermentation. Otherwise you should be all right. Add the thawed concentrate to save volume.

Comment: Might not be a big problem if you don't add a large amount into an already active fermentation. The amount of preservatives in a liter/quart of juice into 5-6 gallons of vigorously fermenting wort is not nearly enough to stop fermentation. Getting the fancy untreated/pasturized only juice is of course better for several reasons...

Answer (score 0):

I made a concoction using welches white grape juice and sugar for a 12%abv.

To defeat the preservative I had to add a massive amount of yeast and several hits of oxygen. I forget the preservative name but it inhibits yeast growth by absorbing oxygen.